# Android Service result Broadcast is not being broadcasted

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a main activity and a service who collects logs form LogCat
The service is running fine, right until the moment it has to broadcast the results back to the main activity
The broadcast of the results `broadcast(logBuffer)` is broadcasted **but never received**
The status broadcast, right after it `broadcast(Status.FINISHED)` is broadcasted **and received fine**.
The LogCat log of the run shows the logs were collected and broadcasted.

*Note: I tried to use sendOrderedBroadcast() but the problem remained.*

Service relevant code:

```
private void broadcast(Status status) {
    Log.d(TAG, "+ broadcast(status: " + status + ")");
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.StatusReceiver.ACTION_STATUS);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("STATUS", status);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "- broadcast()");
}

private void broadcast(ArrayList<String> logs) {
    Log.d(TAG, "+ broadcast(logs: " + logs + ")");
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.StatusReceiver.ACTION_RESULT);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("LOGS", logs);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "- broadcast()");
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {

    .... some background collection work

    broadcast(logBuffer);
    broadcast(Status.FINISHED);
    Log.d(TAG, "- onHandleIntent()");
}
```

Main activity relevant code:

```
public class StatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ACTION_STATUS = "com.devilstate.auxapp.action.STATUS_CHANGED";
    public static final String ACTION_RESULT = "com.devilstate.auxapp.action.RESULTS_READY";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "+ onReceive(context:" + context + ", intent:" + intent + ")");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.w(TAG, action);
        if( action.equals(ACTION_STATUS) ) {

            Status status = (Status) intent.getSerializableExtra("STATUS");
            switch( status ) {
            case COLLECTING:
                if( mState == State.INIT || mState == State.WAIT_FOR_RUNNING ) {
                    setViewState(State.RUNNING);
                }
                break;
            case FINISHED:
                if( mState == State.RUNNING || mState == State.WAIT_FOR_DONE ) {
                    setViewState(State.DONE);
                }
                break;
            }

        } else if( action.equals(ACTION_RESULT) ) {

            logBuffer.clear();
            logBuffer = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("LOGS");
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "- onReceive()");
    }

}
```

LogCat relevant messages:

```
02-19 20:30:13.338: D/LogCollectorService(3880): + broadcast(logs: [02-19 20:17:37.229 I/ActivityManager(10160): Displayed com.devilstate.auxapp/.MainActivity: +8s703ms, 02-19 20:17:37.300 W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(10160): setKernelCountSet(10013, 0) failed with errno -2, 02-19 20:17:44.928 D/MainActivity( 2372): + onStartStopButtonClick(v:android.widget.Button@41035cf8), 02-19 20:17:44.963 D/MainActivity( 2372): - onStartStopButtonClick(), 02-19 20:17:44.980 D/LogCollectorService( 2372): + onHandleIntent(workIntent: Intent { cmp=com.devilstate.auxapp/.LogCollectorService }), 02-19 20:17:44.980 D/LogCollectorService( 2372): + broadcast(status: COLLECTING), 02-19 20:17:45.208 D/MainActivity( 2372): + onReceive(context:com.devilstate.auxapp.MainActivity@41025408, intent:Intent { act=com.devilstate.auxapp.action.STATUS_CHANGED cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] flg=0x10 (has extras) }), 02-19 20:17:45.218 D/LogCollectorService( 2372): - broadcast(), 02-19 20:17:46.128 D/dalvikvm( 2372): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1), 02-19 20:17:46.368 D/dalvikvm( 2372): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1), 02-19 20:17:46.418 D/dalvikvm( 2372): GC_CONCURRENT freed 220K, 5% free 6701K/7047K, paused 8ms+8ms, 02-19 20:17:49.863 W/MainActivity( 2372): com.devilstate.auxapp.action.STATUS_CHANGED, 02-19 20:17:50.030 D/MainActivity( 2372): + setViewState(state:RUNNING), 02-19 20:17:50.038 I/MainActivity( 2372): Current State:WAIT_FOR_RUNNING, 02-19 20:17:50.080 I/MainActivity( 2372): New State:RUNNING, 02-19 20:17:50.080 D/MainActivity( 2372): - setViewState(), 02-19 20:17:50.112 D/MainActivity( 2372): - onReceive(), 02-19 20:17:52.989 I/ActivityManager(10160): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} from pid 10160, 02-19 20:17:53.009 W/WindowManager(10160): Failure taking screenshot for (250x135) to layer 21010, 02-19 20:17:53.039 W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(10160): setKernelCountSet(10013, 1) failed with errno -2, 02-19 20:17:54.309 D/MainActivity( 2372): + onStop(), 02-19 20:17:54.440 D/MainActivity( 2372): - onStop(), 02-19 20:17:54.509 W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(10160): setKernelCountSet(10040, 0) failed with errno -2, 02-19 20:17:56.039 I/ActivityManager(10160): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.devilstate.auxapp/.MainActivity bnds=[400,344][496,440]} from pid 10283, 02-19 20:17:56.039 W/WindowManager(10160): Failure taking screenshot for (250x135) to layer 21010, 02-19 20:17:56.089 W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(10160): setKernelCountSet(10040, 1) failed with errno -2, 02-19 20:17:56.139 D/MainActivity( 2372): + onStart(), 02-19 20:17:56.139 D/MainActivity( 2372): + updateViewState(), 02-19 20:17:56.179 D/LogCollectorService( 2372): + isRunning(), 02-19 20:17:56.179 D/LogCollectorService( 2372): - isRunning(): true, 02-19 20:17:56.215 D/MainActivity( 2372): + setViewState(state:RUNNING), 02-19 20:17:56.215 I/MainActivity( 2372): Current State:RUNNING, 02-19 20:17:56.339 I/MainActivity( 2372): New State:RUNNING, 02-19 20:17:56.339 D/MainActivity( 2372): - setViewState(), 02-19 20:17:56.349 D/MainActivity( 2372): - updateViewState(), 02-19 20:17:56.389 D/MainActivity( 2372): - onStart(), 02-19 20:17:56.589 I/Process (10160): Sending signal. PID: 2372 SIG: 3, 02-19 20:17:56.589 I/dalvikvm( 2372): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3, 02-19 20:17:56.740 I/dalvikvm( 2372): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt', 02-19 20:17:57.519 W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(10160): setKernelCountSet(10013, 0) failed with errno -2, 02-19 20:17:58.869 D/MainActivity( 2372): + onStartStopButtonClick(v:android.widget.Button@41035cf8), 02-19 20:17:58.869 D/LogCollectorService( 2372): + forceStop(): false, 02-19 20:17:58.899 D/LogCollectorService( 2372): - forceStop(): true, 02-19 20:17:58.899 D/MainActivity( 2372): - onStartStopButtonClick(), 02-19 20
02-19 20:30:13.428: D/LogCollectorService(3880): - broadcast()
02-19 20:30:13.428: D/LogCollectorService(3880): + broadcast(status: FINISHED)
02-19 20:30:13.438: D/MainActivity(3880): + onReceive(context:com.devilstate.auxapp.MainActivity@41027a70, intent:Intent { act=com.devilstate.auxapp.action.STATUS_CHANGED cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] flg=0x10 (has extras) })
02-19 20:30:13.438: W/MainActivity(3880): com.devilstate.auxapp.action.STATUS_CHANGED
02-19 20:30:13.450: D/MainActivity(3880): + setViewState(state:DONE)
02-19 20:30:13.450: D/MainActivity(3880): - setViewState()
02-19 20:30:13.450: D/MainActivity(3880): - onReceive()
02-19 20:30:13.478: D/LogCollectorService(3880): - broadcast()
02-19 20:30:13.478: D/LogCollectorService(3880): - onHandleIntent()
```

If it is not clear, I wonder why the result buffer is not received as it should on the MainActivity side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem (very silly really)

I did not add the ACTION_RESULT to the broadcast intent filter. That's why the receiver was not responding to `broadcast(ACTION_RESULT)`. Once I add it all worked perfectly

```
    // Register the broadcast receiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(StatusReceiver.ACTION_STATUS);
    filter.addAction(StatusReceiver.ACTION_RESULT);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    receiver = new StatusReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```